# How to remove/change JQuery UI Autocomplete Helper text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

It seems that this is a new feature in JQuery UI 1.9.0, because I used JQuery UI plenty of times before and this text never poped up.

Couldn't find anything related on the API documentation.

So using an basic autocomplete example with local source

```
$( "#find-subj" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
});
```

When the search matches it shows this related helper text:

> '1 result is available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.'

How can I disable it in a nice way, not by removing it with JQuery selectors.

Comment: in which browser do you see this ? are you able to see the same dialog in jquery ui website

Comment: I have never seen this, can you possibly provide a fiddler or some additional code so we can look into it more?

Comment: for me the issue was that position: relative, was being overridden for the span on which the accessibility stuff was displaying... I just added "!important" and now I can keep the accessibility

Answer (score 155, accepted):

I know this has been asnwered but just wanted to give an implementation example:

```
var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++"
    ];

$("#find-subj").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    messages: {
        noResults: 'no results',
        results: function(amount) {
            return amount + 'results.'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it puts the string "null" in the same place. The solution is to change to: noResults: '', and you will get no message at all.

Comment: Worked for me with noResults:''. Wonder why it's not documented on api.jqueryui.com

Comment: Not sure what `source: availableTags` does? I removed it and I still had no messages.

Comment: @Django Reinhardt that was just copied over from the example in the OP's question. Source defines where the autocomplete data is coming from. For example `availableTags` could be a local variable containing a JSON object of url to word mapping `[{ '/tag/cats': 'Cats', etc... }]` So when the user types `Ca` Cats will show up in the dropdown and when selected or clicked it can populate a hidden field with the url for example.

Comment: This is still valid in 2019. I added availableTags example and a better example of the results function

Answer (score 90):

This is used for accessibility, an easy way to hide it is with CSS:

```
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible { display:none; }
```

Or (see Daniel's comment bellow)

```
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible { position: absolute; left:-999em; }
```

Comment: As you said, it's used for accessibility so people with screen readers  can understand the widget better. By using display: none; you hide it from screen readers as well. Better to move it of screen with position: absolte; left:-999em;

Comment: Instead of `left: -9999px`, you can also use `left: 200%` (200% vs. 100% just to account for any possible browser quirks where 100% doesn't *quite* get it off the screen).

Answer (score 24):

The top answer here achieves the desired visual effect, but defeats the object of jQuery having ARIA support, and is a bit dickish to users who rely upon it! Those who've mentioned that jQuery CSS hides this for you are correct, and this is the style which does that:

```
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}
```

Copy that into your stylesheet instead of removing the message, please :).

Comment: 2019 update: don't use the `clip` property, as it's now deprecated - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip

Comment: Yup this is in the official `jquery-ui/themes/base/core.css`. Make sure to include it.

Answer (score 17):

According to [this blog](http://blog.andrewawhitaker.com/2012/10/08/jqueryui-autocomplete-1-9/):

> We now use ARIA live regions to announce when results become available
>   and how to navigate through the list of suggestions. The announcements
>   can be configured via the messages option, which has two properties:
>   noResults for when no items are returned and results for when at least
>   one item is returned. In general, you would only need to change these
>   options if you want the string to be written in a different language.
>   The messages option is subject to change in future versions while we
>   work on a full solution for string manipulation and
>   internationalization across all plugins. If you’re interested in the
>   messages option, we encourage you to just read the source; the
>   relevant code is at the very bottom of the autocomplete plugin and is
>   only a few lines.
>
> ...
>
> So how does this apply to the autocomplete widget? Well, now when you
>   search for an item, if you have a screen reader installed it will read
>   you something like “1 result is available, use up and down arrow keys
>   to navigate.”. Pretty cool, huh?

So if you go to github and look at the [autocomplete source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/widgets/autocomplete.js), around line 571 you'll see where this is actually implemented.

Answer (score 12):

Adding the jquery css also worked to remove the instructional text.

```
<link
 rel="stylesheet"
 href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Comment: Beware: this is likely to wreck the rest of the styling of your page.

Answer (score 6):

Since this is in there for accessibility reasons it's probably best to hide it with CSS.

However, I would suggest:

```
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible { position: absolute; left: -9999px; }
```

Rather than:

```
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible { display:none; }
```

As the former will hide the item off-screen, but still allow screen-readers to read it, whereas `display:none` does not.

Comment: Instead of `left: -9999px`, just use `left: 200%` (200% vs. 100% just to account for any possible browser quirks where 100% doesn't *quite* get it off the screen).

Answer (score 2):

Well, this question is a bit older, but the text does not show up at all when you include the according css file:

```
<link
 rel="stylesheet"
 href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/YOUR_THEME_HERE/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Of course you have to insert an actual theme instead of `YOUR_THEME_HERE` e.g. "smoothness"

Answer (score 1):

Style it how the jQuery theme itself styles it. A lot of the other answers suggest including a whole stylesheet, but if you just want the relevant CSS, this is how it's done in `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css`:

```
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible { 
    position: absolute !important; 
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); 
    clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery CSS .ui-helper-hidden-accessible is in the themes/base/core.css file.  You should include this file (at a minimum) in your stylesheets for forward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this code right after the autocomplete in your script will push the annoying helper off the page, but the people using screen readers will still benefit from it:

```
$(document).ready(function() { //pushing the autocomplete helper out of the visible page
    $(".ui-helper-hidden-accessible").css({"position": "absolute", "left":"-999em"}) //{"display","none"} will remove the element from the page
});
```

I'm not a fan of manipulating CSS with JS but in this case I think it makes sense. The JS code created the problem in the first place, and the problem will be solved a few lines below in the same file. IMO this is better than solving the problem in a separate CSS file which might be edited by other people who don't know why the .ui-helper-hidden-accessible class was modified that way.

Comment: I've been searching forever trying to solve this problem and your solution worked.

Comment: Instead of `left: -9999px`, just use `left: 200%` (200% vs. 100% just to account for any possible browser quirks where 100% doesn't *quite* get it off the screen).