# jQuery UI autocomplete strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Following is my code:

```
var availableTags = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++",
"Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell",
"Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"];

$("#City").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
});
```

From [**Docs**](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default), the default behavior is a kind of **`dropdown`** the matched items.  But for me it is showing like

**Screenshot:**

> **10 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.**

[image]

Sorry, I couldn't reproduce this behavior in jsfiddle.  The navigation is done using up and down arrow keys.  I don't want this, how can I revert back to default dropdown?  Please share your suggestions.

**Updates:**

With @Anton reference, I was able to remove the validation message, however **the `dropdown` is not showing**.  But I am able to navigate using up/down arrow keys.  Any feedback on this?

Comment: Found something here that might fix the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011127/how-to-remove-change-jquery-ui-autocomplete-helper-text

Comment: try to include it in a function like $(function() {}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this according to this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13091534/1696560) on SO

```
$("#City").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    messages: {
        noResults: '',
        results: function() {}
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 Thanks this helps to remove the validation message, however still the dropdown is not showing only navigation using up/down key.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @user1671639 I'm not sure, but i've been looking around and it might be z-index problems, try this `ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu {
  z-index: 1000;
}`

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `jquery-ui.css` in your project folder and link it.

Edit the `ui-autocomplete` in the above .css and add `z-index = 4000` into that. Your dropdown should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Anton is right.

Also please note I think it's not a best practice to use some id starting in capital :)

```
$("#city")
```

Use this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/franchez/mv9wh/3/) on fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem and solve it with that annoying tooltip by including default css style file for jquery.ui.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" />
```

Just forgot to do this after including jquery-ui javascript source file `jquery-ui.min.js`.