# Drop down input field

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a a drop down field in my search form, but the problem is that I am getting a message: (17 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.) under the input field instead of results.

My code is:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
        $( "#destination" ).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/fantastic/Travels/search_fields",
                data: { term: $("#destination").val()},
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
               success: function(data){
   var resp = $.map(data,function(obj){
        return obj.destination;
   }); 
   response(resp);
}
            });
        },
        minLength: 1
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

my controller code is:

```
    function search_fields(){
    $term = $this->input->post('term', TRUE);   

     $search_data = $this->Travel->search_field($term); 
     echo json_encode($search_data);

}
```

My Model code is:

```
 function search_field($term){

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT distinct(destination) FROM travels_detail WHERE destination LIKE '".$term."%' group by destination");
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

I applied the same code to another site and it is working. but on another site its giving me message "17 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate." and these 17 results show on keyup and keydown button.

Anyone have some idea?? Please tell me

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734823/jquery-ui-autocomplete-strange-behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a matter of css library.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

After placing that library issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct(destination) FROM travels_detail WHERE destination LIKE '".$term."%' group by destination
```

You need to drop the group by destination, it's redundant.

Can you try that and let me know how it looks?

Comment: You're returning an array, i.e. all the values that are true. you need to read them in as seperate values from the array, otherwise they will all be treated as the one singular answer.

Comment: for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++){
   echo $arr[$i]->option[0];
}

Comment: it is working on a separate page but when i configure it with my template it did not show me the results

Comment: You mean your css template? That shouldn't have anything to do with this.

Comment: It was a matter of css, A css library was missing. thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Ah!! Doh! Sorry sir!